# Login in Jabber-net

Tags: c#, .net, xmpp, openfire

I'm trying to write an application with XMPP protocol and Jabber-net.

what is the problem???

```
        JabberClient client = new JabberClient();

        client.User = USER_NAME;
        client.Password = PASSWORD;
        client.Server = SERVER;
        client.Resource = "MyTestClient"; 
        client.Port = 5222;
        client.AutoReconnect = 1;
        client.AutoPresence = false;
        client.KeepAlive = 10;
        client.PlaintextAuth = true;
        client.AutoLogin = true;

        client.OnConnect += client_OnConnect;
        client.OnAuthenticate += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(client_OnAuthenticate);
        client.OnInvalidCertificate += client_OnInvalidCertificate;
        client.OnError += new bedrock.ExceptionHandler(client_OnError);
        client.OnIQ += client_OnIQ;
        client.OnProtocol += client_OnProtocol;

        client.Connect();
```

and the global variable are like these

```
        string USER_NAME = "09371231231";
        string PASSWORD = "09371231231";
        string SERVER = "181.29.101.224";
```

Why I cant login???

Comment: What is the error you get? Which of your event handlers are being called and which aren't? As far as I remember, when working with jabber-net I didin't use AutoLogin, but call login () in onConnect(). (However, this was over a year ago and I don't have access to the code right now)

Comment: the event **OnInvalidCertificate** is called but the event **OnAuthenticate** should be called...

Comment: client_OnIQ <> client_OnInvalidCertificate <> client_OnError <> client_OnProtocol <> client_OnIQ

Answer (score 1):

When the onInvalidCertificate event handler is called, the TLS/SSL certificate of your XMPP server isn't trusted. This usually happens when this certificate is self-signed, is expired or not issued for the IP address but a DNS name. If the certificate is issued to your-server.yourdomain.com you have also to connect to your-server.yourdomain.com and not the IP address for the certificate to be checked.

In this event handler you can tell jabber-net to connect to the server desipte the invalid certificate. IIRC this is done by returning true. For testing this is OK, for a finished product you should present the certificate to the user anyhow (like web browsers do).

**Edit / response to your comments**: The server is telling you, that still something is wrong with your request. Without knowing the actual request it is hard to guess what is the problem. Maybe you can find a hint in the server log. If not, you should have a closer look at the traffic, especially the request that fails.

If you need to sniff the traffic, here is the code I used to disable TLS and compression so that I could see something in wireshark trace:

```
client.SSL = false;
client.PlaintextAuth = true;
client.AutoStartTLS = false;
client.AutoStartCompression = false;
```

Btw, this will also prevent the invalid certificate error, however it should be configurable by the user whether he wants to use TLS or not.

Comment: I returned true. Then on the OnError event, This message has been shown **Error binding resource: <error type="modify" code="400"><bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas" /></error>**.

Comment: But I don't have any resource.

Comment: In your code fragment you haven't set any XMPP resource. Try client.Resource = "MyTestClient"; However, this should be a value that can be modified by the user. Details: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6120#section-7

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364942/error-binding-resource-while-connecting-to-openfire-server-using-jabber-net , I edited the question, But still **Error binding resource** is shown...